# Anywhere server start time

Tags: sqlanywhere

I need to know when the database server has been started, something like when the dbsrv*.exe has been launched. (* for version 9 - 12).

There is a log accessible from the tray icon but with a limited number of rows so I can't see the start time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply that: [PowerShell command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/18/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-see-process-start-time.aspx)